# Python CSV writer with utf-8 code formats

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I am trying to write something in Dutch to a CSV a file and this is what happens

In the following program, ideally, "Eéntalige affiche in Halle !!" should be written in the csv file. However, it's writing "EÃ©ntalige affiche in Halle !!"

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
S="Eéntalige affiche in Halle !!".encode("utf-8")
file=c = csv.writer(open("Test.csv","wb"))
file.writerow([S])
```

In the CSV file== ? "EÃ©ntalige affiche in Halle !!"

Comment: What version of python do you use? I see a unicode decode error in line 3

Comment: @Dhara: It works fine in Python 3. But Python is not at fault here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hence my question... I have Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing data correctly. The problem lies in whatever is *reading* the data; it is interpreting the UTF-8 data as Latin 1 instead:

```
>>> print('E\xe9ntalige affiche in Halle !!')
Eéntalige affiche in Halle !!
>>> 'E\xe9ntalige affiche in Halle !!'.encode('utf8')
b'E\xc3\xa9ntalige affiche in Halle !!'
>>> print('E\xe9ntalige affiche in Halle !!'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1'))
EÃ©ntalige affiche in Halle !!
```

The U+00E9 codepoint (é, LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE) is encoded to two bytes in UTF-8, C3 and A9 in hex. If you treat those two bytes as Latin1 instead, where each character is always only *one* byte, you get `Ã` and `©` instead.

There is no standard for how to treat CSV files and encoding, you'll need to adjust your encoding to the intended target application to read this information. Microsoft Excel reads CSV files according to the current codepage, for example.

If your CSV reader is expecting Latin 1, by all means, encode to Latin 1 instead.

Comment: Working perfect in LibreOffice but not in MS Excel. 

Thank You all :)

Comment: Thanks Martijn - this helped me solve a problem where Excel wasn't reading the data correctly and I was thinking that it was a problem with the Python code.